# Bind data to gridview with existing columns but it also creates new columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

Im trying to fill my gridview with already existing columns, but instead of filling only the existing columns the code creates also new columns filled with the data

Here is my code:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True");
            connect.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor                
+ " FROM SysteemSensorInfo";

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        }
```

I know it has something to do with the "new dataset" but i kinda blacked out at the moment and am pretty new to the programming world.

Can anyone please tell me to rewrite my code in the right way.

This is what happens now:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to set ```GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;``` before any binding (for example, in aspx markup)

Comment: This helped tym32167, i replaced GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false; to my page_load. And it worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to set **GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false** at **first**:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;            

        connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True");
        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor              
                          + " FROM SysteemSensorInfo";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
           GridView1.DataBind(); 

            connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LP12;Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True");
            connect.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DrukSensor, FlowSensor                
+ " FROM SysteemSensorInfo";

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        }
```

Try clear your datagrid after bind date.

Comment: This did not work for me, it stayed the same as before but thanks for your ideas!